# VBA Excel extracting data from website with changing date in URL

Tags: vba, excel

I am extremely new to VBA so any help is appreciated.  I am trying to extract data from this website https://www.census.gov/construction/bps/txt/tb3u201601.txt.  The 201601 in the url represents jan 2016.  I would like to create a program that cycles through all the months until 2003 and puts all the data in an excel spreadsheet.  So far I have written something that isolated the date (below) but I cannot figure out how to have it loop through the dates I need.  Thanks again.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3 As String
Dim str As String

str1 = "URL;https://www.census.gov/construction/bps/txt/tb3u"
str2 = "201601"
str3 = ".txt"
str = str1 & str2 & str3

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    str, Destination _
    :=Range("$A$2"))
    .Name = "tb3u201601_4"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Loop at the parent

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim thisDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim string2 as String

    startDate = DateSerial(2003, 1, 1)
    endDate = DateSerial(2016, 4, 1)
    Dim i As Integer

    Do
        thisDate = DateAdd("m", i, startDate)
        string2 = Format(thisDate,"yyyyMM")
        Call Macro2 (string2)
        i = i + 1

    Loop While (thisDate <= endDate)

End Sub
```

Change Macro2 to accept string parameter

```
Sub Macro2(str2 as string)
....
```

and remove this line in Macro2

```
str2 = "201601"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help danielle. However, when I added all this to my code nothing happened.  Just for clarification, where are the results of macro1 being labeled as str2?

Comment: have edited my answer to make it clearer. Result of macro1 is string2 that is being passed to Macro2.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need a couple of nested loops, one for the months, and one for the years. You can dimension each part as an `Int`, and then call `cStr()` on each of them to covert them back to strings and combine them together.

```
Dim iYear, iMonth as Int

For iYear = 2003 to 2015
    For iMonth = 1 to 12
        str2 = cStr(iYear) & cStr(iMonth)
        'The rest of your code here...
    Next iMonth
Next iYear
```

You'll likely also need to find some way to dynamically change where you're starting each table. If the tables are the same number of rows, you can replace your `Range($A$2)` reference with something like `Range(Cells(iRow, 1).Address)`, and add to  `iRow` every time you go through the loop. (`iRow = iRow + [the number of rows in the table]`

Comment: I think your code will generate 20031,20032,20033,20034...  etc as str2 which is not intended by the CPslo.